# CSS not working with drupal7 after adding base_url

Tags: drupal, routes, drupal-7

I am fairly new to Drupal. I just got an existing project and installed it in my local machine (/var/www/html/drupal/myproject).

First I comment out `$base_url` and the page works ; the site comes with CSS, images, everything works fine (but only in the '/' path).

But when I add:

```
$base_url = '127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject';
```

The site won't load CSS or images.

I get this notice:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal_settings_initialize() (line 774 of /var/www/html/drupal/myproject/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

It does load the HTML itself, though.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up wrong path as `127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject`, add `http://`before it like this.

`$base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject';`

For more information, see `$base_url` expamples in settings.php.

Hope works for you. Thanks